# Is there a way to check that none of the rows in a grouping contain a value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2012

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT  ordDetails.OrderId
FROM    orders.OrderDetail ordDetails
WHERE   ordDetails.Class <> 'O'
GROUP BY ordDetails.OrderId
```

But this does not work quite right.  `OrderId` is not unique in this table (hence the `group by` clause).  My `where` clause only removes OrderIds that have ALL rows with a `Class` of 'O'.  (If even one row has a value other than 'O', then that `OrderId` is included in the result.)

I want all the OrderIds that have NO rows with a value of 'O'.

Normally I would just use an aggregate function like `MAX` or `MIN`.  But alas, `MAX` returns 'R' and `MIN` returns '' (empty string).

What I really need is an aggregate function that checks that none of the values in the aggregate match a parameter.  Unfortunately there is no such aggregate function.

**Is there a way to say (in a `group by` query) "only give me results that have no rows matching an 'O'"?**

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Note table aliases should be short (1, 2 maybe 3 chars), else they serve no purpose.

Comment: @DaleK - Hmm, we have a difference of opinion then.  I always focus my table aliases on improving readability for the next person to come across my query.  I find I much prefer an alias of `ordDetail` over `o` or `od` when reading another's query (or my own after a few years).  (Though it, of course, makes little difference in a tiny example like I have shown above.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
select distinct
   o.OrderId
from
   OrderDetails as o
where not exists
(
   select 1
   from
      OrderDetails as o2
   where
      o2.OrderId = o.OrderId and
      o2.Class = '0'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use:

```
SELECT  ordDetails.OrderId
FROM    OrderDetails ordDetails
GROUP BY ordDetails.OrderId
HAVING sum(case when ordDetails.Class='O' then 1 else 0 end)=0
```

Answer (score 1):

And more options. First using the except set operator

```
select distinct OrderId from @OrderDetails
except
select OrderId  from @OrderDetails where Class = 'O'
;
```

And conditional counting with HAVING clause

```
select Orderid 
from @OrderDetails
group by OrderId
having count(case Class when 'O' then 1 else null end) = 0
;
```